# Как обновить записи в БД Yii

Tags: php, yii

Подскажите, как обновить колонку age у всех записей в БД у которых category = 2;
Патаюсь так:

```html
//Так обновляет все записи без условия
$user = User::updateAll(['age' => '21']);

//Так обновляет только колонку age в одной записи у которой категория = 2 
$user = user::findOne(['category' => '2']);
$user->age = '21';
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по документации

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord#updateAll()-detail

> Updates the whole table using the provided attribute values and
> conditions.
>
> For example, to change the status to be 1 for all customers whose
> status is 2:
>
> Customer::updateAll(['status' => 1], 'status = 2');
>
> Warning: If you do
> not specify any condition, this method will update all rows in the
> table.

```
 User::updateAll(['age' => '21'], 'category = 2');
```